# A confusing case of codeblocks in markdown

Tags: markdown

```
void Board::move(Direction direction)
```

{
    Board pre_move_board(*this);

```
prepareForNextMove();

switch (direction) {
case UP:
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
            moveVertically(i,j,UP);
    break;
case DOWN:
    for (int i = dimension-1; i >= 0; --i)
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
            moveVertically(i,j,DOWN);
    break;
case LEFT:
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
            moveHorizontally(i,j,LEFT);
    break;
case RIGHT:
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
        for (int j = dimension-1; j >= 0; --j)
            moveHorizontally(i,j, RIGHT);
}
```

As you can see in the codes above, the "code form" just misteriously skipped the second line. You can try the code in your markdown editers. Why is that? And how to fix the problem?

Comment: Have you got 4 spaces at the start of the line that is skipped?

Comment: @beryllium The line of code in question doesn't start with 4 spaces. However, I'm leaving it unedited as fixing it would completely invalidate your question. For future reference, all code must start with 4 spaces for the markdown editor to recognize it as code.

Comment: @timlyo Oh that's it. but as I already ctrl+K and thus created little '  ' before I paste the code in, why the number of spaces would matter?

Comment: @computerfreaker thks

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information.

Comment: @timlyo thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

On the second line, indent by adding four spaces before you begin writing to make it an indent block, or in this case a code block.

[image: From Mou]

Here's an example from the Mou Markdown Editor for mac.

Comment: In particular, the line with the `{`.